# Convert company shares to token

Tags: spl-token

I want to convert my company shares to token and airdrop it between co-workers and users. when my company sell a product How i can share profit between any person have my company tokens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many strategies to share profits for token holders.
I think the most straightforward mechanism is to buy & burn tokens with the profit so that it will increase worth of your company token which it also beneth holders as well.

Comment: Good idea, thanks

Comment: If it's good, why don't you vote on my answer? ;)

Comment: Excuseme, I tried a lot, but vote button don't work for me